# Mobile list collapsible items

Tags: qooxdoo

I am trying to create a list of collapsible containers. The container should collapse and expand. I have created an example list item renderer.

```
qx.Class.define("mb.ui.list.QuotaWeekListRenderer",
{
  extend : qx.ui.mobile.list.renderer.Default,

  members :
  {
    __collapsible : null,
    __weeksContainer : null,

    _init : function()
    {
      this.ignoreBase;

      this.__collapsible = this._createCollapsible();

      this.add(this.__collapsible);
    },

    setTitle : function(title)
    {
      this.ignoreBase;

      if (title && title.translate)
      {
        this.__collapsible.setTitle(title.translate());
      }
      else
      {
        this.__collapsible.setTitle(title);
      }
    },

    addWeek : function(value)
    {
      var label = new qx.ui.mobile.basic.Label(value);
      this.__collapsible.add(label);
    },

    _createCollapsible : function()
    {
      return new qx.ui.mobile.container.Collapsible();
    },

    // overridden
    reset : function()
    {
      this.ignoreBase;

      this.setTitle("");
      this.__collapsible.getContent().removeAll();
    }
  }
});

var page = new qx.ui.mobile.page.NavigationPage();
page.setTitle("List");
page.addListener("initialize", function() 
{

  // List creation
  var list = new qx.ui.mobile.list.List({
    configureItem : function(item, data, row) 
      {
         item.setTitle("Week " + parseInt(data.weekNo));
         for (var i = 0, l = data.weekDates.length; i < l; i++)
         {
           item.addWeek(data.weekDates[i]);
         }
      },
      createItemRenderer : function()
      {
        return new mb.ui.list.QuotaWeekListRenderer();
      }    
  });

  // Create the data
  var data = [{title: "title1", weekNo: 1, weekDates : ["1/2/2014", "2/2/2014"]},
              {title: "title2", weekNo : 2, weekDates : ["2/3/2015", "9/3/2015"]}];


  list.setModel(new qx.data.Array(data));

  page.getContent().add(list);
},this);

this.getManager().addDetail(page);

page.show();
```

The above can be run in [Playground](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#Hello%20World-mobile)

My problem is that the items don't expand on 'tap'. Listener toggles the "collapsed" property of the container, but it has no effect on the DOM element. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

something like this, maybe?

[Playground example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22var%2520page%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.mobile.page.NavigationPage()%253B%250Apage.setTitle(%2522Hello%2520World%2522)%253B%250Apage.addListener(%2522initialize%2522%252C%2520function()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520application%2520%253D%2520qx.core.Init.getApplication()%253B%250A%2509%2509var%2520dataAlumnos%253B%250A%2509%2509%250A%2509%2509dataAlumnos%2520%253D%2520%255B%250A%2509%2509%2509%257Btitle%253A%2520%2522Administrar1%2522%252C%2520path%253A%2520%2522alumnos1%2522%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509%257Btitle%253A%2520%2522Administrar2%2522%252C%2520path%253A%2520%2522alumnos2%2522%257D%250A%2509%2509%255D%253B%250A%2509%2509%250A%2509%2509var%2520listAlumnos%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.mobile.list.List(%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509configureItem%253A%2520function(item%252C%2520data%252C%2520row)%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509item.setTitle(data.title)%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%252F%252Fitem.setSubtitle(data.subtitle)%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509item.setSelectable(true)%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509%257D%250A%2509%2509%257D)%253B%250A%2509%2509%250A%2509%250A%2509%2509listAlumnos.addListener(%2522changeSelection%2522%252C%2520function(e)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252Fvar%2520path%2520%253D%2520dataAlumnos%255Be.getData()%255D.path%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252Fapplication.getRouting().executeGet(%2522%2522%2520%252B%2520path)%253B%250A%2509%2509%257D)%253B%250A%2509%2509%250A%2509%2509listAlumnos.setModel(new%2520qx.data.Array(dataAlumnos))%253B%250A%2509%2509%250A%2509%2509var%2520collapsibleAlumnos%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.mobile.container.Collapsible(%2522Alumnos%2522)%253B%250A%2509%2509collapsibleAlumnos.add(listAlumnos)%253B%250A%2509%2509this.getContent().add(collapsibleAlumnos)%253B%250A%2509%2509%250A%2509%2509dataCursos%2520%253D%2520%255B%250A%2509%2509%2509%257Btitle%253A%2520%2522Administrar3%2522%252C%2520path%253A%2520%2522alumnos3%2522%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509%257Btitle%253A%2520%2522Administrar4%2522%252C%2520path%253A%2520%2522alumnos4%2522%257D%250A%2509%2509%255D%253B%250A%2509%2509%250A%2509%2509var%2520listCursos%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.mobile.list.List(%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509configureItem%253A%2520function(item%252C%2520data%252C%2520row)%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509item.setTitle(data.title)%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%252F%252Fitem.setSubtitle(data.subtitle)%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509item.setSelectable(true)%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509%257D%250A%2509%2509%257D)%253B%250A%2509%2509%250A%2509%2509listCursos.setModel(new%2520qx.data.Array(dataCursos))%253B%250A%2509%2509%250A%2509%2509listCursos.addListener(%2522changeSelection%2522%252C%2520function(e)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252Fvar%2520path%2520%253D%2520this.getModel().getItem(e.getData()).path%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252Fapplication.getRouting().executeGet(%2522%2522%2520%252B%2520path)%253B%250A%2509%2509%257D)%253B%250A%2509%2509%250A%2509%2509var%2520collapsibleCursos%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.mobile.container.Collapsible(%2522Cursos%2522)%253B%250A%2509%2509collapsibleCursos.add(listCursos)%253B%250A%2509%2509this.getContent().add(collapsibleCursos)%253B%250A%257D)%253B%250A%250Athis.getManager().addDetail(page)%253B%250A%250Apage.show()%253B%250A%250A%250A%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22mobile%22%7D)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. What you created is two lists in two collapsible containers. I need one list of collapsible containers as items. 
I understand that the list Provider clones the elements. The consequence is that on tap listener's target is showing that is collapsed, but element on the page is not. Any actions withing the listener are performed on an item have no effect on the list item I actually tap).